Workflow for modelling the final prodcut of a chemical reaction
I have done some DFT simulations before in cp2k and siesta but the kind of systems I am about to study is new to me so I would appreciate it if I got helpful suggestions from the experts.
The system is experimentally synthesized starting from an aqueous solution of two polymers  which is then drop-cast on a surface. The surface is heated afterwards to remove water. I am only interested in studying the properties of the final product (such as the geometry, the energy levels, etc).
What is the best workflow to study such a system using DFT (Due to limitations on resources I have access only to DFT packages)? I am thinking of optimizing each polymer separately, optimizing the surface, then put them together in one run.
Thanks.
er

Why do you think the surface matters? Is that part of the reaction?

Do you already know the identity and/or structure of the product? If you do that will remove you first big hurdle :)

The surface matter a lot and I do not exactly know the molecular structure of the product. I only have SEM images and I want to see how exactly the atoms are bonded.
